# Adapting search algorithm to search the minimum in a database in $O(\sqrt{N}\log(N))$ queries

Tags: quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm

I need some hint on how to adapt grover's algorithm to search the minimum in a database with $N=2^n$ elements in $O(\sqrt{N}\log(N))$ queries with probability of success $\geq 2/3$. I know I can do it by basically choosing randomly a "pivot" and then applying Grover to find a number smaller than that, then update my pivot. But is there something more to it?

Answer (score 5):

There is an algorithm by [Dürr and Høyer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9607014.pdf) that seems to solve your problem. This algorithm finds the correct answer in $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N})$ time with probability $1/2$.

The crux is that they have an oracle which flips the phase of all states with a smaller value than the currently selected one.

Comment: I have seen that, but it's overkill. I am looking for something more naive.

Comment: @Karl What do you mean by more naive?